# PHP display last data where name is same

Tags: php, mysql

How to display last data where name is same. I think my $result is wrong. Please help me solve it. Thank you

```
$SearchQ = "SELECT * FROM tblperson where Id = ".$_GET['Id'];
$SearchResult = mysql_query($SearchQ,$link);
$StaffRec = mysql_fetch_array($SearchResult);
```

```
<input type="text" name="txtPastDate" id="txtPastDate" value="<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblvisit order by tblvisit.Id desc limit 1 where tblvisit.PatientName = $StaffRec['Name']");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $row['VisitDate'];
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
?>"/>
```

Comment: your query is wrong, `ORDER` belongs after the `WHERE`. See [the MySQL SELECT reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)

Comment: And the same comment as in to a million other posts: **stop** using `mysql_` function and move to `mysqli_` or `PDO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query would be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from tblvisit 
                       WHERE tblvisit.PatientName = '".$StaffRec['Name']."'
                       ORDER BY tblvisit.Id desc limit 1");
```

After the `condition` only you have to apply the `order`.